# How can i remove extra white space in expo BarCodeScanner

Tags: react-native, expo

iOS is working fine BarCodeScanner take full screen but when i use android there is extra white space.

```
<BarCodeScanner
  onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : this._handleBarCodeScanned}
  style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill, { flex: 1 }]}
/>
```

I have also checked by giving a different style like but no luck

```
style={{
  height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
  width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
}}
```

[image: White space example]

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be an issue in recent versions of expo-barcode-scanner. One possible workaround is to explicitly set the dimensions of the BarCodeScanner to the dimensions of the screen:

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

<BarCodeScanner style={{
    width: Dimensions.get('screen').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('screen').height,
}} />
```

Note that setting it to the dimensions of the window, like you tried, does not work.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I have changed the project from expo to react-native cli for some reason.

Comment: @ZeeshanAnsari Not a problem... Still, you can use these expo modules with react-native cli.

Comment: OMGGGGG this is workkk, thank you. i've been searching this for hours!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

FrederikVds's answer not worked for me. So I have changed the expo camera which has the barcode scanner functionality too. You can do it like following:

```
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera'

<Camera
  onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : this._handleBarCodeScanned}
  style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
/>
```

Optionally you can use `ratio='16:9'`.

If you need to use expo libraries in react-native cli, you should follow these [setups](https://docs.expo.io/bare/installing-unimodules/)

Here is the issue discussion: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/5212

Comment: Yea, this approach seems to work better

Answer (score 1):

```
import { BarCodeScanner, BarCodeScannerResult } from 
'expo-barcode-scanner'


const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;

export default function XYZ() {            

 return(
  <BarCodeScanner
   onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : 
   handleBarCodeScanned}
   style={{ width: height - 188, height: height, 
   alignSelf: "center" }}
  />
 )
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit too late to answer the question but here's a solution that helped:
Use this function to calculate the dimensions needed to be passed to the barcode style:

```
const calcDimensions = (width, height) => {
  const aspectHeight = width * 1.777777778;
  const aspectWidth = height * 0.5625;
  if (aspectHeight < height) {
    return {
      height: height,
      width: aspectWidth,
    };
  } else {
    return {
      height: aspectHeight,
      width: width,
    };
  }
};

const {newHeight, newWidth} = calcDimensions(screenHeight, screenWidth);

      <BarCodeScanner
        onBarCodeScanned={handleBarCodeScanned}
        style={{
          
          width: newWidth,
          height: newHeight,
        }}
      />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).